# Strange Behavior with AWS S3 Lifecycle Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

As we know that we can not move objects to S3 IA or S3 IA One Zone only after passing 30 days.
So when we try to migrate those objects after one day in S3 for example.We will get this message:

[image: S3 IA Storage class message]

Now.My question why this is not happening with Glacier.In fact,I could change the Lifecycle policy to make transition to Glacier even after one day in S3 Standard which is normally is not possible because Glacier request that objects are stored for at least 90 days.So we expect to get a message same like for S3 IA.

[image: S3 Deep Archive Storage class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why this is not happening with Glacier.

**Because this is only applicable for transitioning TO s3- standard-IA or s3 one zone IA**. There is no limitation **to transition TO Glacier**

[As per docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html#before-deciding-to-archive-objects) Before you transition objects from the S3 Standard or S3 Standard-IA storage classes to S3 Standard-IA or S3 One Zone-IA, you must store them at least 30 days in the S3 Standard storage class.

> Glacier request that objects are stored for at least 90 days

There is misunderstanding on your part 90 days holds good when object is stored inside glacier stored class not for that object has to be stored for 90 days in other class

From docs

> Number of days you plan to keep objects archived – S3 Glacier Flexible Retrieval and S3 Glacier Deep Archive are long-term archival solutions. The minimal storage duration period is 90 days for the S3 Glacier Flexible Retrieval storage class and 180 days for S3 Glacier Deep Archive.

Comment: if it helped you, acceptance as answer would be appreciated so that it helps others in the future